# How to find logical 'or' operator (||) from a sequence using Regex Python

Tags: python, regex, regular-language

I want to find and replace the logical "or" operator (`||`) from my sequence. How can I do it?

Following is the code, I'm trying

```
import re 
sequence = "if(ab||2) + H) then a*10"
expr = re.sub(r"||","_or_",sequence)
print (expr)
```

Expected answer should be

```
if(ab_or_2) + H) then a*10
```

Comment: Why not `.replace("||", "_or_")`?

Comment: Because I want to learn how I can do it with regex.

Comment: @Naeem But you don't need any of the features of regular expressions

Comment: Warning: Neither `str.replace()` or `re.sub()` can properly handle `'if a||b then "||x||x||" else "--x--x--"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `escape sequence` '`\`' here since '`|`' is a special character.

[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> '|'
>
> A|B, where A and B can be arbitrary REs, creates a regular
>   expression that will match either A or B. An arbitrary number of REs
>   can be separated by the '|' in this way. This can be used inside
>   groups (see below) as well. As the target string is scanned, REs
>   separated by '|' are tried from left to right.

So you need to do :

```
expr = re.sub(r"\|\|","_or_",sequence)
```

Or, using `re.escape()` : thanks to [@Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428131/how-to-find-logical-or-operator-from-a-sequence-using-regex-python/46428167?noredirect=1#comment79813595_46428167) for pointing this out

```
expr = re.sub(re.escape("||"),"_or_",sequence)
```

And you will get :

```
IN : sequence = "if(ab||2) + H) then a*10"
OUT : 'if(ab_or_2) + H) then a*10'
```

**Edit :**

If you are not required to just use `regex`, you can directly use `replace` for the string. ie,

```
sequence.replace('||','_or_')
```

Here you won't have to worry about the special character.

Comment: Or you can use `re.escape()` for escaping arbitrary string literals: `re.sub(re.escape("||"),"_or_",sequence)`

Comment: Yup, that too. Thanks for pointing that out. Will add that bit too.

Comment: Got it, Thank you

Comment: @Naeem , glad to help.